# UITableView IndexPathForCell return errors

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my UITableView, each cell has a custom UISwitch. I am saving the switch information in an NSMutableArray, with the intent of using it to save the state information whenever the user changes to a different table.

To do this, I need to obtain the row information of the cell, so that I can flip the corresponding "YES" or "NO" in the NSMutableArray.  I attempt to do it as such:

```
UICustomSwitch *temp = (UICustomSwitch *)sender;
UITableViewCell *cell =  (UITableViewCell *)temp.superview;
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

After this I have

```
NSLog(@"Path was: %@", path);
```

Now, when I output path, I get something like:

```
Path was: <NSIndexPath 0x4b25590> 2 indexes [0, 1]
```

However, when I change the NSlog to path.row, the program crashes.  I've not found a reason for this, and I use path.row in other places as well.  Can anyone help explain why this is happening?

Edit:

For example, when I do this:

```
 NSLog(@"Path was: %d", path.row);
```

It crashes.

Answer (score 2):

`NSIndexPath.row` returns a plain unsigned integer (`NSUInteger`), not an object, so you'll need to change your `NSLog` format specifier to from `%@` to `%u`.  By using `%@`, it's using the integer as a memory address, which very likely points to some memory that is not an object at all.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did make the relevant changes to NSLog.  It still causes the program to pause, then crash with no report. (I keep having these "no report" crashes, no idea what causes that)

Comment: Nothing here can cause any crash. There must be something else.

Comment: [switchStates replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

Is the next possible location of crash (and is why I ended up putting that NSLog into place). It is an NSMutableArray, and works fine when I put a constant in, instead of path.row.  So if path.row is secretly not the right type, and it's not springing an error on me, that may be why. But from what I've read it should work fine.

Comment: Take a look at the backtrace to see where it's actually crashing.  The only way the `replaceObjectAtIndex` would crash is if you get an NSRangeException because the index is beyond the length of the array.

Comment: One problem I'm constantly having is that I can't see a stack trace sometimes (most the time, if I can see a stack trace, I can figure it out, these questions come from when the simulator doesn't give me one).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

`NSLog(@"Path was: %@", path.row);` ? `path.row` is type of `NSUInteger`. You could use '%d' instead of '%@'.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... I'm not sure this counts as an answer, but I ended up restarting the computer and it started working again.  So... Yeah, I really have no idea what in the world was going on.